# PrimeNg css not loading (Not styling components)

Tags: html, css, angular, frameworks, primeng

The thing that works for me is that I get a button with the html code. But the button isn't styled so it's a plain button without any css characteristics.

Down is the code that should be relevant to primeNg.
So my problem is that primeNg isn't styling my components.

edit: Once trying to re run the application I get the error: `InvalidConfigError... ensure the file is valid JSON` Which is the Style section.

index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

.angular-cli.json

```
"styles":{
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"

  }
```

app.component.html

```
<button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-warning"></button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

app.module.ts

```
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
imports: [
  ButtonModule
]
```

Comment: You don't have to import stylesheets in `index.html` when you already stated them in `styles` array.

Comment: did you add primeng styles in angular-cli.json and did you re-run the project. because whenever there is .angular-cli.json it's not affected untill you re run the project.

Comment: you can see my angular-cli.json links in my question. "styles":{
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css"

  } which I've added manually

Comment: dont have the styles in the index.html

Comment: Yes but that wouldn't still change anything at all for my problem

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38338342/prime-ng-styles-not-applying-angular2